# CVXPY constraint vector conditionals values inside

Tags: python, indexing, constraints, cvxpy

First of all I'm a newbie with the cvxpy module in python.

I have a doubt about the constraint in the CVXPY library in python.

I'm creating a vector weights that contains some specifications.
My problem is when I create the constraint list. My specifications are:

1. weight cant be greater than 0.2
2. weight sum cant be greater than 1.0
3. weight cant be less than 0
4. all the weights bigger than 0.07 cant sum more than 0.5

The problem is the last one. I dont know how to filter values inside weight inside is own in the constraint definition.
I think that is not the correct way to do it. But I cant find something that can help/understand in the CVXPY webpage.

```
import cvxpy as cv
w = cv.Variable(mu.shape[1])
constraint=[
            cv.sum(w)==1,                 #all the values have to sum 1
            cv.max(w)<=0.2,               #each value cant be bigger than 0.2
            cv.min(w)>=0.0,               #each value cant be less than 0
            # w[w>0.07].sum()<0.5         #MY PROBLEM, I dont know how to express this in cvxpy
           ]
```

Thank you in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
cv.sum([x for x in w if x > 0.07]) < 0.5
```